# CSS endless rotation on the Y axis

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to do animation of the coin that rotates infinitely on the Y axis, but I can't quite make this work. Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/kaeatjag/
As you can see it only animates once, one rotation and then starts from the beginning. How can i fix this?

```css
.coin {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, black 50%);
  animation: coin-rotate 1s both infinite;
}

@keyframes coin-rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }

  to {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin"></div>
```

Comment: Just add an extra frame to animation! https://jsfiddle.net/kaeatjag/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add an extra frame to the animation and bring it back to original state.

Transform from `0% (0deg) -> 50% (180deg) -> 100% (0/360deg)`

Note: Adjust the animation duration as per your need

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kaeatjag/1/)

```css
.coin {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, black 50%);
  animation: coin-rotate 2s both infinite;
}
@keyframes coin-rotate {
  0 {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="coin"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your animation so that it's end-state is similar to it's starting-state. For such looping animations, you need to make the transformation to come back to starting state.

```
@keyframes coin-rotate {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0);
  }

  50% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a hack, but if what you want is for the animation to smoothly transition you can do this:

**CSS** + **HTML** code:

```css
.coin { 
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      font-size: 0.5px;
      animation: coin-rotate 8s infinite;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, red 50%, black 50%);
      border-radius: 100px;
      }
       

.a {
   opacity: 0.1;
   }
        
@keyframes coin-rotate  {  
                        0%  {
                            transform: rotateY(0deg); 
                            transform-origin: 50% 5% 0;
                            }  
                        100% {
                             transform: rotateY(360deg); 
                             transform-origin: 50% 5% 0;
                             }  
                        }
```

```html
<div class="coin"><a>.</a></div>
```

Strangely, if you attempt to

1. Remove the full stop
2. Set the font size to zero or
3. Set the opacity to zero

The animation gets that horizontal motion effect you may have been obliquely referring to when you said:

> As you can see it only animates once

So by inference the above solution should probably fix what seems to be the true issue, if only the symptom, rather than the overarching problem.

It appears that, in my browser at least, the CSS processor responsible for handling rotations checked for the presence of a 'visible object' and was failing to consider the background property an 'object' for the purposes of rotation, which was causing a glitch where the animation disappeared off to the side in a manner counter-intuitive to the most logical reading of the code.

The above code is about as beautiful as I could make it for the moment.

I've also changed a few of the rotation parameters while I was experimenting to find a solution, but there shouldn't be too much of a problem with changing them back or messing about with the numbers until you get something you feel works well.

Hope this is helpful!